# What Design pattern is this peudocode for?

Tags: design-patterns

In an interview I was asked this quistion :

```
X a = new X("param");
Y b = new Y(a);
Z c = new Z(b);
```

I was thinking about Creational DP : AbstractFactory but I am not so sure.

So what DP is this code ?

Thank you

Comment: They might mean Decorator, but can be almost anything depending on what is inside the classes and how they're used.

Comment: With that in mind, don't worry if you didn't pass the interview, since based on the question their communication skills are far from advanced.

Comment: @bereal yeah not wirry about passing the interview but I did not find a solid answer to it as design patterns still fuzzy in my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the constructor does it, it could be the [`Decorator Pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). For all that we know, by the end of it all `a` could be something completely different.

Comment: Yes by going to a book i found exampl as new A ( new B (...)). Thank you

Comment: Classes in decorator pattern are sharing the same interface. From pseudocode in question, I say it is dependency injection, not a decorator.

Answer (score 1):

This is `Dependency injection`. You pass some dependencies through a constructor.

In the other hand `Decorator Pattern` will be indicated here:

```
X a = new A("param");
X b = new B(a);
X c = new C(b);
```

As `A, B, C` share same type `X`.